# fetch all associated data from sqlite database when i click on an item in listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, onitemclicklistener

I want to access specific data from my sqlite database related to the item clicked onItenclicklistener.is there any way to do it?
I am using base adapter listview.I am trying to do it from last 2 days but its not done till now.any help will be appriciable.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            PagesSqliteData pagesSqlite = new PagesSqliteData();
            List<PagesSqliteData>pagesSqliteDataArrayList = new ArrayList<PagesSqliteData>();
            pagesSqlite.setToc_name(bookingsSqliteDataArrayList.get(position).getToc_name());
            pagesSqlite.setContent(compositionSqliteDataArrayList.get(position).getContent());
            pagesSqlite.setCompletion(bookingsSqliteDataArrayList.get(position).getCompletion());
            pagesSqlite.setPageNo(compositionSqliteDataArrayList.get(position).getPage_no());
            pagesSqlite.setCategory_id(bookingsSqliteDataArrayList.get(position).getCategory_id());
            pagesSqlite.setBooking_id(bookingsSqliteDataArrayList.get(position).getBooking_id());
            pagesSqlite.setTable_of_content_id(bookingsSqliteDataArrayList.get(position).getTable_of_content_id());
            pagesSqliteDataArrayList.add(pagesSqlite);

            Intent i = new Intent(MyBookings.this, Pages.class);
            i.putExtra("LIST", (Serializable) pagesSqliteDataArrayList);
            startActivity(i);

    }
```

Database Tables:

```
 String CREATE_MYBOOKINGS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + MYBOOKINGS + "("+bookingid + " TEXT," +categoryid + " TEXT," +completion + " TEXT," +compositionid+ " TEXT," + contributorid + " TEXT,"+ languageid + " TEXT," +booking_created+ " TEXT,"+ tocname + " TEXT,"+tocid+ " TEXT,"+categoryname+ " TEXT," +cdnId + " TEXT,"+secretToken + " TEXT,"+booking_uploaded + " TEXT,"+ booking_modified + " TEXT"+")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_MYBOOKINGS_TABLE);


 String CREATE_COMPOSITIONS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + COMPOSITIONS + "("+bookingid_c + " TEXT," +compositionId + " TEXT," +compositionContent +" TEXT," +compositionImage + " TEXT," + compositionCreated + " TEXT,"+ wordCount+ " TEXT,"+ compositionPageno + " TEXT"+")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_COMPOSITIONS_TABLE);
```

Comment: whats the error ?

Comment: @Hunt i want all the pages of a book present in database in list view...when i click on a book name.

Answer (score 0):

You must implement Serializable in your PagesSqliteData class.

```
public class PagesSqliteData implements Serializable
```

and in your activity use this code:

```
array= (ArrayList<PagesSqliteData >) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("LIST");
```